# Java NIO filesystem

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, filesystems, nio

I am trying to create a Java Swing Application in which I will be storing some image files and CSV files in a subdiretory

```
   com/p/d/resources/project/MyProject
```

In above project there will be other sub-directories in which I will be storing the images and CSV files. How to access above directory in seamless way. That is even if I run this project as a JAR(which I will ultimately do) or on Eclipse it should give me the access to above directory either as java.nio.file.Path OR java.io.File.
     I know I can create a filsystem to iterate JAR but the same code doesn't work when I run it as application in Eclipse. Following is the code I am using for JAR file scenario:

```
      String projectLocationPath = ApplicationProperties
                .get(PhaserDesktopConstants.PROJECT_LOCATION_PATH);
        CodeSource src = MainController.class.getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource();
        if (src != null) {
            URL jar = src.getLocation();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jar.toURI().normalize(), null);
            Path projectDirectory = fs.getPath(projectLocationPath);
            if (!Files.isDirectory(projectDirectory)) {
                return null;
            }
          }
```

Where PhaserDesktopConstants.PROJECT_LOCATION_PATH represents path I gave above. I want to run above code in both scenarios with JAR and without JAR.
     I get following path

```
    file:/D:/shailesh/technical/work/eclipse_ws/Phaser%20Desktop/bin/
```

when I run it in Eclipse and calling

```
    FileSystems.newFileSystem(..)
```

with this gives me exception

```
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
```

Following some posts on SO I tried hardcoding and changing the path from

```
     file:/D:/shailesh/technical/work/eclipse_ws/Phaser%20Desktop/bin/
```

to

```
  file:///D:/shailesh/technical/work/eclipse_ws/Phaser%20Desktop/bin/
  file://D:/shailesh/technical/work/eclipse_ws/Phaser%20Desktop/bin/
  file:///shailesh/technical/work/eclipse_ws/Phaser%20Desktop/bin/  
  file://shailesh/technical/work/eclipse_ws/Phaser%20Desktop/bin/
```

but none worked.

Just an Update: 
 when I debug in eclipse  my JAR it gives me following path as location of CodeSource:

```
 file:/D:/shailesh/technical/PhaserD.jar
```

however error is same its not able to create the filesystem. My OS is Windows 7. JDK 7

Comment: So the files are stored within the context of your application Jar or stored somewhere on the file system?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No they are stored in the JAR itself. By the way I resolved the problem of handling JAR. so in above code I just append "jar:" to path "file:/D:/shailesh/technical/PhaserD.jar" and it seems to be working

Comment: @MadProgrammer I also solved the file system directory inspection by checking if uri ends with ".jar". If it doesn't then I construct a File instance by using the URI instead of creating a filesystem like I do in case of JAR.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Even though I have solved my problem for now it doesn't feel right.I dont feel manually appending "jar:", so that correct FilSystemProvider implementation is used is good. My main concern is  handing it agnostically by building a file system whether I am  inspecting a JAR or a normal directory on file system

Comment: Take access resources stored within the jar itself, you should be using Class#getResource, you should avoid using absolute paths where ever possible

Comment: @MadProgrammer do mean using something like MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource()? OR MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()? for later i cannot get Directory which i want to iterate over. I will try with getResource though

Comment: Okay, if you're trying to list the contents of Jar file, then this can't be done, or at least it can't be done without first knowing the source jar file

Comment: @MadProgrammer I already know the location of JAR or a normal bin directory in which the first structure I mentioned exists(com/p/d/resources/project/MyProject). I find it using  CodeSource src = MainController.class.getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource(); Its just that I cannot get reference to the directory I want to iterate over with same code or somhow identifying Filsystemprovider dynamically

Comment: If you can (safely) gain a reference to the Jar, then you fill need to use `JarFile` to open the Jar and read it's entries manually, you won't be able to use the `File` base (NIO included) APIs to do this

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am using Java 7 NIO API which allows me to build a file system on a JAR/ZIP and iterate/walk the tree with new API. Please see below link :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `.` with `./../` to switch to a parent directory or with any reference path you'd like. `p` holds the absolute path, and you can remove the `toAbsolutePath()` to obtain the `referencePath`.

```
Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work when I run this in JAR as well. Because when I run the JAR default File system should not be used and I will be creating new file-System with JAR